# Issue regarding grid view powershell

Tags: powershell

I  have a  text file where server names are mentioned and my script find status of the specific service for the servers and it goes through some condition to start or stop the service. Now I want to display the output on a single grid view with the pc and the status but when i execute my script it gives status output in separate grid for each server .I want everything in single grid view

```
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\computer.txt
$Service = "wisvc"


foreach ($computer in $computers) {
   

   $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
   if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Running")
   {
   $Servicestatus.Stop() 
$Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer 
$Servicestatus | select-object Name,Status,MachineName | Out-GridView
   } 

else{
$Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer

$Servicestatus | select-object Name,Status,MachineName |  Out-GridView
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As bvbeek stated, your `Out-GridView` call is inside the loop. When using a foreach statement like you are you'll need to collect the output into a variable. Do not create and array `@()` and append to it `+=` as suggested since that is unnecessary and can be very slow when dealing with lots of data. Instead you can simply collect the output of the entire loop to a variable then display that with Out-GridView

```
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\computer.txt
$Service = "wisvc"

$results = foreach ($computer in $computers){

    $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
    if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Running"){

        $Servicestatus.Stop() 

    }

    get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer | select-object Name,Status,MachineName

}

$results | Out-GridView
```

Also as you can see there was a lot of duplicated code that served no purpose. You collected the service status again in each branch of the if/else so simply move that outside of the if and eliminate the else clause.

You could also take advantage of the pipeline by changing to a `Foreach-Object` loop

```
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\computer.txt
$Service = "wisvc"

$computers | ForEach {

    $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
    if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Running"){

        $Servicestatus.Stop() 

    }

    get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer | select-object Name,Status,MachineName

} -OutVariable results | Out-GridView
```

This will achieve the same results as the previous

1. Collect the output to the variable `$results`
2. Display the output to `Out-GridView`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround to stream the foreach to out-gridview:

```
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\computer.txt
$Service = "wisvc"

& {

  foreach ($computer in $computers) {   
    $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
    if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Running") {
      $Servicestatus.Stop() 
    } 
    $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer 
    $Servicestatus | select-object Name,Status,MachineName
  } 

} | out-gridview
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is you are placing the Out-GridView within the foreach-loop.
Please try this:

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\computer.txt
$Service = "wisvc"
$Array = @()
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    $Servicestatus = Get-Service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
    if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Running") 
    {
        $Servicestatus.Stop() 
        $Servicestatus = Get-Service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer 
        $Array += $Servicestatus | Select-Object Name, Status, MachineName
    } 
    else 
    {
        $Servicestatus = Get-Service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer
        $Array += $Servicestatus | Select-Object Name, Status, MachineName
    } 
}

$Array | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Please do not encourage `$array = @()` and `$array +=` - instead simply do `$array = foreach($c in $comp){...}`. The former is a bad practice

Comment: @DougMaurer I understand, thanks for correcting me.my opinion is to write readable code, and not crop everything on a single line.